# Joining multiple tables that return n results

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a JSON api. I'm aiming for speed, and making the least amount of queries possible by joining related data.

I can do `joins`. But I'm confused about something. How do I join multiple tables that return `n` number of records? For example, lets say I have the following tables:

```
- Users
- Addresses
- Orders
```

I want to get use `5` from the database, and their address, and orders, in one query.

Joining `Users` and `Addresses` would return all the `Addresses` the user has. Each `Address` as a row, with `Users` columns. But, when you add another table that can also return `n` results, how does the database return that?

I hope this isn't too confusing. I struggled to put it into better words.

Comment: Some example code of what you've tried, the results you've had and what you expect might be good.

Comment: @kjtl it's not really a question I have for a current problem, I am more concerned about how the database returns the results.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a JOIN from a table A to a table B `ON A.UserID = B.UserID`, and B.UserID is not unique, it returns as many rows as B dictates and fields selected from A are duplicated.

To put in a example, if you do:

```
SELECT a.Name, B.Adress FROM users A INNER JOIN adresses B ON A.UserID = B.UserID
```

And adresses contains 3 rows for ID 1 (Let's call him Max), then the output would be:

```
Max | 123 Fake St.
Max | 456 Real St.
Max | 789 Imaginary St.
```

The same would apply if you add a third table. Records from tables A and B will be duplicated for each match in table C.

Comment: So if I joined the 3, and i wanted to return all `Orders` from the query I would just group by the orders ID?

Comment: Grouping is a different thing, by default you will get all the rows matching your JOIN's `on` statement.

Comment: I think there's a little misunderstanding, its so hard to give context in comments. I'll open another question.